# How to use Indexed_search with TYPO3

Tags: forms, content-management-system, typo3, indexed, typo3-6.2.x

I searche to use the modul indexed_search of TYPO3 on the version 6.2.

I find some tutorials but when I tried them,  the searchBox appear, but I don't have the result. Only the page with the ID that I put in constant :

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.searchUID = 9
```

The code :

```
  TEST < lib.searchbox


TEST = COA_INT
  TEST {
    stdWrap.prefixComment = 2 | lib.searchbox
    10 = TEXT
    10.typolink.parameter = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.searchUID}
    10.typolink.returnLast = url
    10.wrap = <div id="indexedsearchbox"><form action="|" method="post" id="indexedsearch"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    20 = COA
    20 {
      wrap = <tr> | </tr>
      10 = TEXT
      10.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      10.data = GPvar : tx_indexedsearch |sword
      10.wrap = <td><input name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]" value="|" class="searchbox-sword" type="text" /></td>
      20 = COA
      20 {
        wrap = <td align="right">&nbsp;|</td>
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[sections]" value="0" />
        20 = TEXT
        20.value = <input name="tx_indexedsearch[submit_button]" value="Search" type="hidden" />
        30 = TEXT
        30.value = <input name="search" src="fileadmin/templates/image/Search.png" value="Search" class="searchbox-button" type="image" />
      }
    }
    30 = COA
    30 {
      wrap = <tr>|</tr>
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = Advanced search »
      10.typolink.parameter = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.searchUID}
      10.typolink.additionalParams = &tx_indexedsearch[ext]=1
      10.wrap = <td align="right" colspan="2">|</td>
      if.isTrue = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.showAdvanced}
    }
    wrap = | </table></form></div>
  }
```

Comment: Did you activate indexing of your pages at all according to the manual? http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/doc_indexed_search/4.2.1/#general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a stupid thinks, but I don't create the record for the plugin Indexed_Search. So, for you, I put how we can do that (I search during long time so...)

1) Go on the page Search (id = 9 here) on the backend zone.

2) Create a new record and choose General Plugin in the tab Plugins

3) Select the plugin Indexed_Search in the tab Plugin